# Need CSS help for a wordpress website, trying to create text cards and my text just gets cutoff because of Text Line Height, Padding and font size

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am experiencing an issue with my body text. If the text is longer than the width of the content container, it overlaps on itself instead of starting a new line. This is what it looks like on mobile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCydu.jpg.

Also, I want to keep the line height and padding t as already set.

So, Is there a workaround?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You got any code to show?

Comment: https://shumaar.com/ghalib-ki-shero-shayari/ is the page that has issues

Comment: element.style {
}
.et_pb_text_26 h3 {
    font-family: 'Crete Round',Georgia,"Times New Roman",serif;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

Answer (score 0):

Your line-height is set to `line-height: 0.2em;` on `.et_pb_text_5 p` you need to increase it to `line-height: 1.2em;` I know you said you want to keep it the same but that's what causing the issue I think.

You've also got `<p>&nbsp;</p>` not sure this is needed add a margin-bottom

Answer (score 0):

add in your css and check text card.

```
p{ 
    line-height: 1.7em !important; 
    margin-bottom: 0px !important; 
}
```